# Navigation bar gets hidden on tapping UISearchbar's cancel button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

Issue with navigation bar. Scenario is as -

After successful search, I tapped on a result/cell in table view and move to next screen for details of search result, coming back on search results screen tapped on cancel button. It resets the UISearchBar but it hides the navigation bar.

1. Before Search

[image: This is navigation bar state before search]

2. On tapping search bar

[image: navigation bar state after tap on search bar]

3. After coming back from details screen to search results screen **(Navigation bar gets hidden)**

[image: Here navigation bar gets hidden when coming back to search results screen]

I have tried

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

in

```
searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried setting the navigationBarHidden on the UINavigationController itself?

Comment: Navigation bar's visibility is ON under navigation controller